# Counting the number of days excluding Sundays between two dates and creating a new column in R DataFrame

Tags: r, date-difference

I have a data.frame in R in which includes two variables with a Start-Date and an End-Date. I would like to add a new column with the number of days between the two dates and reduce the result by the number of sundays in each interval. I tried it like below but it doesn't work:

```
Data$Start <- as.Date(Data$Start, "%d.%m.%y")
Data$End <- as.Date(Data$End,"%d.%m.%y")

interval <- difftime(Data$Start, Data$End, units = "days")
sundays <- seq(from = Data$Start, to = Data$End, by = "days")
number.sundays <- length(which(wday(sundays)==1))

Data$DaysAhead <- interval - number.sundays
```

I get the error message in the seq() function, that it has to have the lenght 1 but I don't understand how I can handle this. Can somenone help me out with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized with an updated data set that there's a problem with the solution above, when Start-Date and End-Date aren't in the same year. I still want to count the days except Sundays starting on the 20.12.2020 until 10.01.2021 for example. The error message showing up in that case is that the sign with the argument "by" is wrong. I just can't manage to get it running . If I turn the dates around, the output makes no sense and the number of days is too high. What do I have to do to get this running over the year-end?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that works:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Start = c("01.01.2020", "01.06.2020"), 
  End = c("01.03.2020", "01.09.2020")
)  

Data$Start <- as.Date(Data$Start, "%d.%m.%Y")
Data$End <- as.Date(Data$End,"%d.%m.%Y")

interval <- difftime(Data$End, Data$Start, units = "days")
sundays <- lapply(1:nrow(Data), function(i)seq(from = Data$Start[i], to = Data$End[i], by = "days"))
number.sundays <- sapply(sundays, function(x)length(which(lubridate::wday(x)==1)))

Data$DaysAhead <- interval - number.sundays
```

The problem is that `seq()` isn't vectorized, it assumes a single start and single end point.  If you putt it inside of a loop (like `lapply()`) it will work and generate the relevant sequence for each start and end time.  Then you can use `sapply()` to figure out how many sundays and since the returned value is a scalar, the return from `sapply()` will be a vector of the same length as `interval`.

Comment: I realized with a updated data set that there's a problem with the solution above, when Start-Date and End-Date aren't in the same year. I still want to count the days except Sundays starting on the 20.12.2020 until 10.01.2021 for example.

Comment: apologies, it needs to be a capital "Y" in the date format `"%d.%m.%Y"`.  If you change that in the start and end  date formatting commands above, that will work.  I edited the answer to fix the problem.